# Solve a system of odes with scipy - how to reference different indexes?

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I have a system of ODEs that depend on a matrix of data. Each ODE should reference a different column of data in its evaluation.

```
import numpy as np
n_eqns = 20
coeffs = np.random.normal(0, 1, (n_eqns, 20))
def dfdt(_, f, idx):
    return (f ** 2) * coeffs[idx, :].sum() - 2 * f * coeffs.sum()

from scipy.integrate import ode
f0 = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, n_eqns)
t0 = 0
tf = 1
dt = 0.001

r = ode(dfdt)
r.set_initial_value(f0, t0).set_f_params(range(n_eqns))

while r.successful() and r.t < tf:
    print(r.t+dt, r.integrate(r.t+dt))
```

How can I specify that each ODE should use the idx value associated with its index in the system of ODEs? The first equation should be passed `idx=0`, the second `idx=1`, and so on.

Comment: FYI: The *first* argument of your `dfdt` must be `t`, the time variable.  It must be there even if your equations are autonomous (i.e. they don't explicitly depend on the `t` variable).  Take a look at the first example in the Examples section [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks! I didn't know that. I updated my question to reflect that. My code actually runs with no error now. Now I need to verify it to make sure it's doing what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `dfdt` takes and returns the state and derivative, respectively as arrays (or other iterables). Thus, all you have to do is to loop over all indices and apply your operations accordingly. For example:

```
def dfdt(t,f):
    output = np.empty_like(f)
    for i,entry in enumerate(f)
        output[i] = f[i]**2 * coeffs[i,:].sum() - 2*f[i]*coeffs.sum()
    return output
```

You can also write this using NumPy’s component-wise operations (which is quicker):

```
def dfdt(t,f):
    return f**2 * coeffs.sum(axis=1) - 2*f*coeffs.sum()
```

Finally note that using `f` for your state may be somewhat confusing since this is how `ode` denotes the derivative (which you call `dfdt`).